# Kendo datasource result filtering the foreign key attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, kendo-ui

```
public DataSourceResult 
Get([ModelBinder(typeof(Nexgen.Web.Helpers.DataSourceRequestModelBinder))]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var sourceResult = _customerService.GetPagedCustomers(request);

            return sourceResult;
        }
```

my client side is passing filter to filter the grid

```
filterSearchTerm.filters.push(
                    //{
                    //    field: "CustomerFirstName",
                    //    operator: "contains",
                    //    value: searchTerm
                    //},
                    //{
                    //    field: "CustomerLastName",
                    //    operator: "contains",
                    //    value: searchTerm
                    //},
                    //{
                    //    field: "CompanyName",
                    //    operator: "contains",
                    //    value: searchTerm
                    //},
                    //{
                    //    field: "CustomerNumber",
                    //    operator: "contains",
                    //    value: searchTerm
                    //},
                    {
                        field: "CompanyName.CustomerAddress",
                        operator: "contains",
                        value: searchTerm
                    }
                    );
```

I have kendo datasource result which works fine when i use normal field from table but i am unable to search on fields which are present as foreign keys

Comment: Any luck with this? I have a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24489860/kendo-ui-datasource-filter-on-releated-data

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a while back and contacted Telerik support about this my issue was related to DateTime values not being parsed and they advised that this is down to the nested properties being returned back as string values no matter what type they are.

To get around this they suggested to either flatten the model or template things out to get it to work.

This would also mean that any filtering/sorting etc would need to be custom built as well.